# Assertions in abstract superclass scala creating NPE

Tags: scala, require, abstract, object-initialization

The following code, when entered in REPL

```
abstract class A { val aSet: Set[Int]; require(aSet.contains(3)) }

class B extends A { val aSet = Set(4,5,6) }

new B()
```

gives a null point exception, rather than an invariant failure.

What would be the best idiom to solve this problem?

---

Similar questions:

[Code Contracts: Invariants in abstract class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29123695/code-contracts-invariants-in-abstract-class)

[Private constructor in abstract class Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28649425/private-constructor-in-abstract-class-scala)

and also online commentary: https://gist.github.com/jkpl/4932e8730c1810261381851b13dfd29d

Comment: This is because of the order with which constructors are called. Not sure whether that could work for you, but you can work around this by making `aSet` a `def` (in both the `abstract class` and its implementation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare a `val`, several things happen:

1. The compiler makes sure that enough space is allocated for the variable when an instance of the class is initialized
2. An accessor-method is created
3. Initializers that setup the initial values of the variables are created.

Your code

```
abstract class A { val aSet: Set[Int]; require(aSet.contains(3)) }
class B extends A { val aSet = Set(4,5,6) }
new B()
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
abstract class A { 
  private var aSet_A: Set[Int] = null
  def aSet: Set[Int] = aSet_A
  require(aSet.contains(3)) 
}

class B extends A {
  private var aSet_B: Set[Int] = Set(4,5,6) 
  override def aSet: Set[Int] = aSet_B
}

new B()
```

so, the following happens:

1. Memory for `aSet_A` and `aSet_B` is allocated and set to `null`.
2. Initializer of `A` is run.
3. `require` on `aSet.contains(3)` is invoked
4. Since `aSet` is overridden in `B`, it returns `aSet_B`.
5. Since `aSet_B` is `null`, an NPE is thrown.

To avoid this, you can implement `aSet` as a lazy variable:

```
abstract class A { 
  def aSet: Set[Int]
  require(aSet.contains(3)) 
}

class B extends A {
  lazy val aSet = Set(4,5,6) 
}

new B()
```

This throws the `requirement failed` exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed
```

---

Obligatory link to Scala's FAQ:

- [Why is my abstract or overridden val null?](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/initialization-order.html)

List of related questions:

1. [Why does implement abstract method using val and call from superclass in val expression return NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51426017/why-does-implement-abstract-method-using-val-and-call-from-superclass-in-val-exp/51426770#51426770)
2. [Overridden value parent code is run but value is not assigned at parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50703986/scala-overridden-value-parent-code-is-run-but-value-is-not-assigned-at-parent/50705388#50705388)